# Python Multiprocessing Map Returns Unordered Results

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a simple multiprocess pool script using map to get back the results in ordered like if it were executed sequentially.

*Note - Please ignore the "(1-3A-D)".  They are not part of the output and are there for illustration purposes.  Assume that it is the sequence multiprocessing executes.*

```
import base64
import getpass
import os

from ssh.ssh_module import SSH
from multiprocessing import Pool

username = ''
password = ''
cmd = 'uptime'

def runcommand (server):

    print ('Proccess ID: %d' % (os.getpid ()))
    ssh = SSH (server, username, password)
    if ssh.connect ():
        print (ssh.command (cmd))

    ssh.close ()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    username = input ('Username: ')
    # Encode password for SSH
    password = getpass.getpass ('Password: ')
    password = base64.b64encode (password.encode('utf-8'))

    servers = ['192.168.100.1', '192.168.100.2', '192.168.100.3']
    with Pool (processes = 2) as pool:
        pool.map (runcommand, servers)
```

**Output:**

```
(virtual) [user@centos python]$ ./multiprocess.py 
Username: spongebob
Password: 
(1A) Proccess ID: 24528
(1B) SSH into 192.168.100.1
(2A) Proccess ID: 24529
(2B) SSH into 192.168.100.2
(1C) Successfully logged in!
     00:15:24 up 4 days,  8:16,  0 users,  load average: 0.12, 0.10, 0.20

(1D) SSH session closed.

(3A) Proccess ID: 24529
(3B) SSH into 192.168.100.3
(2C) Successfully logged in!
     00:15:26 up 7 days,  6:17,  0 users,  load average: 0.10, 0.11, 0.09

(2D) SSH session closed.

(3C) Successfully logged in!
     00:15:47 up 5 days,  6:41,  0 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.10, 0.17

(3D) SSH session closed.
```

As you can see, the results are returned randomly which I thought using 'pool.map' supposed to be ordered.  The order of which IPs/System are executed first is not important but the output has to be in the right order so that it makes sense.  Any idea on how to fix it so I can get the desire output below?

```
(1A) Proccess ID: 24528
(1B) SSH into 192.168.100.1
(1C) Successfully logged in!
     00:15:24 up 4 days,  8:16,  0 users,  load average: 0.12, 0.10, 0.20

(1D) SSH session closed.

(2A) Proccess ID: 24529
(2B) SSH into 192.168.100.2
(2C) Successfully logged in!
     00:15:26 up 7 days,  6:17,  0 users,  load average: 0.10, 0.11, 0.09

(2D) SSH session closed.

(3A) Proccess ID: 24529
(3B) SSH into 192.168.100.3
(3C) Successfully logged in!
     00:15:47 up 5 days,  6:41,  0 users,  load average: 0.14, 0.10, 0.17

(3D) SSH session closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

`Pool.map` returns the results in the same order as they were scheduled but does not ensure they are executed in the same order.

Sequential execution would defeat the purpose of using `multiprocessing`. If you need things to be executed sequentially just use `map`.

Comment: If what's you're saying is true, then what's the purpose of imap_unordered ()?

Comment: `imap_unordered` does not ensure the results are ordered. None of `map` based method ensure that the *execution* of the given function will appear in the correct order. To try it out, just return the `server` parameter from your `runcommand` function. You will see that `map` returns them in the same ordered while `imap_unordered` doesn't.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve, is to log to `stdout` in an ordered fashion which is impossible to ensure as the different processes might take different times to execute their logic. You might very likely get process1 to log after process2 if the SSH commands are taking different times to execute (network hiccup for example). See: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-a-single-file-from-multiple-processes

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve the desired output by removing the messages within the SSH class and move it to the caller.  It's a matter of using .join () to construct the message sequence.  It's not the prettiest but it's now ordered.

```
import base64
import getpass
import os

from cet.ssh_module import SSH
from multiprocessing import Pool

username = ''
password = ''
cmd = 'uptime'


def runcommand (server):

    print ('Proccess ID: %d' % (os.getpid ()))
    ssh = SSH (server, username, password)
    s1 = 'SSH into %s' % server
    if ssh.connect ():
        s2 = 'Successfully logged in!'
        s3 = ssh.command (cmd)

        ssh.close ()
        s4 = 'SSH session closed.\n'

        output = '\n'.join ([s1, s2, s3, s4])

        return output
    else:
        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':

    servers = ['192.168.100.1', '192.168.100.2', '192.168.100.3']

    username = input ('Username: ')
    # Encode password for SSH
    password = getpass.getpass ('Password: ')
    password = base64.b64encode (password.encode('utf-8'))

    with Pool (processes = 4) as pool:
        results = pool.map (runcommand, servers)

    for i in results:
        print (i)
```

**Output**

```
(virtual) [user@centos python]$ ./multiprocess.py 
Username: spongebob
Password: 
Proccess ID: 40764
Proccess ID: 40763
Proccess ID: 40766
SSH into 192.168.100.1
Successfully logged in!
 17:25:33 up 8 days, 23:51,  0 users,  load average: 3.04, 2.05, 1.43

SSH session closed.

SSH into 192.168.100.2
Successfully logged in!
 17:25:17 up 2 days,  1:26,  0 users,  load average: 0.44, 0.42, 0.72

SSH session closed.

SSH into 192.168.100.3
Successfully logged in!
 17:25:15 up 8 days, 23:27,  0 users,  load average: 2.37, 2.35, 2.03

SSH session closed.
```